# Как отфильтровать ненужные, пустые группы в списке групп пользователей? Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Сравниваю дату содержащуюся в массиве групп пользователей `$res_arr["DATE_ACTIVE_TO"]` с текущей датой `$datenow`. Как отфильтровать пустые группы с которым сравнивается текущая дата? (`array('filter' => array("GROUP_ID" => '7'))` не работает) Получается следующее:

```html
<?
global $USER;
$arfilter = Array(
            "ID" => $_REQUEST['MANAGER_ID'].' | '.$_REQUEST['USES_ID'],
   "UF_TO_KVALIF"=> "1",
            "GROUP_ID" => "7",
        );
        $arParameters = array(
            'SELECT' => array("UF_*")
        );
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="asc"), $arfilter, $arParameters);
$is_filtered = $rsUsers->is_filtered; // отфильтрована ли выборка ?

while($arUser = $rsUsers->Fetch()):


$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($arUser["ID"], array('filter' => array("GROUP_ID" => '7')));
$datenow = date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("FULL")), time());
while ($res_arr = $res->Fetch()){

$result = $DB->CompareDates($datenow, $res_arr["DATE_ACTIVE_TO"]); 
if ($result==1) echo $datenow." > ".$res_arr["DATE_ACTIVE_TO"];
}

endwhile;

?>
```

[image: echo $datenow]

Comment: в фильтрах попробуйте указать `'=GROUP_ID' => 7,`

Comment: @Nikolaj Sarry  пробую так `$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($arUser["ID"], array('filter' => array('=GROUP_ID' => 7)));` не фильтруется

Comment: метод `GetUserGroupList` принимает на вход только один параметр - айди пользователя, других параметров у него нет, а вы зачем-то пихаете ему еще что-то о чем он понятия не имеет.

Comment: для проверки отобранных групп на пустоту можно использовать метод `CGroup::GetList` ([дока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cgroup/getlist.php)) в ней через фильтр указываем сколько должно быть пользователей в обрабатываемых группах, а после того как отобрали непустые группы работаем с ними.